# Display tree nodes in DFS order with prefuse

Tags: tree, visualization, traversal, depth-first-search, prefuse

Is it possible to display a node at a time,as a reaction to a button click lets say, from a prefuse tree structure in DFS order using prefuse visualization primitives and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of each node manually with `setVisible(boolean visible)`.